# Why my value output wont work?

Tags: angular, typescript

gaiz! I'm trying to make this to-do list, but I have problem. When I input value in text field it does not add to array of list elements. On the other hand, when I console.log it, it works. So, what am I missing? Here is the code.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <input type='text' name='unos' #unos  placeholder="unesi zadatak" /> 
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="dodaj(unos.value)">dodaj</button>

    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let el of elementi">
       <span>{{ el.sadrzaj }}</span> <span><input type='checkbox'></span>
         <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="ukloni(el)">ukloni</button>
      </li>      
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Element } from '../element.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-element-liste',
  templateUrl: './element-liste.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./element-liste.component.css']
})
export class ElementListeComponent implements OnInit {

  elementi: Element[] = [
    {sadrzaj: 'kupi kefir'},
    {sadrzaj: 'idi na trening'},
    {sadrzaj: 'izjedi picu'}
  ];

  ukloni(item: Element){
    this.elementi.splice(this.elementi.indexOf(item), 1);
  }

  dodaj(item: Element) {

    this.elementi.push(item);
    console.log(item);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with current implementation

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="dodaj(unos.value)">dodaj</button>
```

this will return string as output , and its not type of element.

So you have to do as below take input as `string`, create element and push it

```
dodaj(item: string) {
    const element : Element = {sadrzaj: item};
    this.elementi.push(element );
    console.log(item);
  }
```

Comment: and reason of - 1? @bugs

Comment: @Vatroslav - please do accept upvote if worked for you